# Latex to docx conversion issues using pandoc - missing information?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert elsarticle (Elsevier Latex template) tex file prepared in LaTex in to docx file using pandoc. I used the following command for conversion and it is working fine but with some issues.

`pandoc --citeproc input.tex --bibliography=mybiblio.bib -o output.docx`

In the output file I am not getting the (i) author information (it has the names but no affiliation and email as was given in Latex file). (ii) No section heading for Abstract and Keywords (iii) no section heading for References (it has listed all the references but if it is possible to extract the heading as well then it would be helpful instead of manually editing every converted tex-to-docx file.)

Suggestions/commands would be helpful for dealing with these issues. Thank you

Comment: I need the final output in Ms Word format (docx). If I use tex3ht and get the output in HTML then using pandoc how to get the final conversion in docx?

Comment: tex4ht can convert to OpenDocument XML, which can be read by MS Word. Try `make4ht -f odt filename.tex`

Comment: I am getting number of following errors when I ran that command
Compilation errors in the htlatex run...